# How to create conda virtual environment with python==2.7.12

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I have tried to put the exact version on the command like:
`conda create --name tst python==2.7.12`
which resulted:
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
So I found this: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2712/
And I wanted to know how to create conda env with this tarball file.

Note: I'm running on wsl env : Ubuntu 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2

Comment: Why do you need to use 2.7?

Comment: ubuntu 5.4 seems wildly out of date. Is this the most recent version you can install?

Comment: @Dennis It is the dependencies for the code that I wanted to clone

Comment: @C.Nivs I haven't check it yet, but I have just installed it with Microsoft store in the early of this year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `python==X` with `python=X` (where X is the version) and for the version from `2.7.12` to `2.7`

`conda create --name tst python=2.7`

Comment: I want to install this exact version because if you use "conda create --name tst python=2.7" it will installed 2.7.18 and it seem to cause the dependency problem with the code that I'm dealing with

Comment: The lowest version that you can install from conda is `2.7.13` [source](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/files?version=2.7.13). Use this command to install it ```conda create --name tst python=2.7.13```

Comment: Besides that you can't install Python from Conda unless you do it manually, https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2712/

Comment: Okay, So I have to create whatever version it has then install the exact version and swap the runtime later then. thanks.